# python, using unpack_from and fmt

Tags: python, struct

hi i am trying to make sense of a piece of code and when i run it here is an error in this area of code. i think there is a fundemental error with itbut it could be just because there is no input invoked to it

```
from cstruct import struct

class MateNET(object):
"""
Interface for the MATE RJ45 bus ("MateNET")
This class only handles the low level protocol,
it does not care what is attached to the bus.
"""
    TxPacket = struct('>BBHH', ('port', 'ptype', 'addr', 'param'))  #  Payload is always 4 bytes?
    QueryPacket = struct('>HH', ('reg', 'param'))
    QueryResponse = struct('>H', ('value'))
```

the struct function is

```
 def struct(fmt, fields):
     fmt = Struct(fmt)
     test = fmt.unpack_from(''.join('\0' for i in range(fmt.size)))
       nfields = len(test)

       if len(fields) != nfields:
             raise RuntimeError("Number of fields provided does not match the struct format (Format: %d, Fields: %d)" % (nfields, len(fields)))
```

error is:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\pymate\matenet\FX_inverter_controller.py", line 1, in <module>
    from matenet import MateFX
  File "C:\pymate\matenet\matenet.py", line 30, in <module>
    class MateNET(object):
  File "C:\pymate\matenet\matenet.py", line 36, in MateNET
    TxPacket = struct('>BBHH', ('port', 'ptype', 'addr', 'param'))  # Payload is always 4 bytes?
  File "C:\pymate\matenet\cstruct.py", line 14, in struct
    test = fmt.unpack_from(''.join('\0' for i in range(fmt.size)))
TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'str'
```

i am pretty new here and also new to python so execuse my noob questioning skills

Comment: from cstrucy import struct is part of the code not the question

Comment: Can you edit your question and fix the part following "the struct function is". Theres no function definition and what is `Struct`?

Answer (score 0):

in python 3.x you have to add bytes(your bytes).encode rather than the previous 2.x format. it becomes

```
test = fmt.unpack_from(bytes(''.join('\0' for i in range(fmt.size)).encode()))
```